# jQuery UI Datepicker Gravity Forms minDate 2 days after 5pm

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to setup a date field using Gravity Forms in wordpress, to display the min date 2 days after if current time is >= 5pm and excluding weekends.

I found the solution for excluding the weekends at
[Gravity Forms jQuery No Weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016233/gravity-forms-jquery-no-weekends)
Here is the solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766031/ian-rogers

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
// destroy default Gravity Form datepicker
jQuery("#input_1_1").datepicker('destroy');
// create new custom datepicker
var oneWorkingDays = new Date();
var adjustments = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]; // Offsets by day of the week
oneWorkingDays.setDate(oneWorkingDays.getDate() + 1 + adjustments[oneWorkingDays.getDay()]);
jQuery("#input_1_1").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends, minDate: '+1d', gotoCurrent: true, prevText: '', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/calendar.png', buttonImageOnly: true });
```

});

So, I will appreciate if someone could help me integrate the other solution, that is displaying the min date 2 days after if current time is >= 5pm.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an answer by myself..
Here is the code that I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
    jQuery("#input_1_1").datepicker('destroy');
    jQuery("#input_1_1").datepicker({ 
    minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 12 ? 2 : 0,
    beforeShowDay: jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends, minDate: '+1d',
   });
 });
</script>
```